# The webview app opens with a blank white screen

Tags: android, android-webview

I have created webview app, and the app opens up with a with a blank white screen. It does not load anything even on reloading the webpage using swipetorefresh

MainActivity.java

```
package app.freeairdrop.io;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private WebView webView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientDemo());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
       // webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

        webView.loadUrl("https://freeairdrop.io/");

        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);


        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        webView.reload();
                        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }
        );

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to handle app links.
        Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
        String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
        Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();
        webView.loadUrl(String.valueOf(appLinkData));
    }



    private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            if (uri.getHost() != null && (url.startsWith("https://freeairdrop.io/") || url.startsWith("https://www.freeairdrop.io/"))) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
        }
    }


    private class WebChromeClientDemo extends WebChromeClient {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        else {
//            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    // This method is used to detect back button
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (this.webView.canGoBack()) {
            this.webView.goBack();
            return;
        }
        Builder dialog = new Builder(this);
//        dialog.setTitle((CharSequence) "Exit App");
        dialog.setMessage((CharSequence) "Do You Want To Exit The App ?");
        dialog.setPositiveButton((CharSequence) "YES", (OnClickListener) new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setNegativeButton((CharSequence) "CANCEL", (OnClickListener) new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).show();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="app.freeairdrop.io"

    >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:appCategory="productivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name="app.freeairdrop.io.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="freeairdrop.io" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The deeplinks to app are working perfectly great, just the app opens everytime with a blank screen.

Comment: Please mention activity_main.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)
```

Comment: if this doesn't work please add logs to your question for better understanding the issue.

Comment: can you post the logs of the app that you get in logcat?

Comment: Pages can show blank if this flag is not enabled and they are made on HTML5 and require Dom Storage

Answer (score 0):

First, please you check HAXM /hrdware accelerate is Run and installed on android studio.
Second, please use chrome browser as default client browser for your webview on your device.
Third, uninstall your apk installed for this project, and restart device, and then , create new build/install this project or your device....

and you can follow the instruction for other like, enable hardware accelerate in manifest, using webchromeclient and etc... it work for me